Babel/Parcel throwing "This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining'" on build - ReactFlow
This error, as well as nullishCoalescingOperator is being thrown when I try to build my app using parcel, which contains the React Flow library. Each error is being caught when transpiling the library files in node_modules.
I am using an outdated version of node (v14.17.3) as to handle other dependencies, but from what I know, this shouldn't interfere.
Example error:
node_modules\@reactflow\core\dist\esm\index.js:57:18: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining'

function Attribution({ proOptions, position = 'bottom-right' }) {
> 57 |     if (proOptions?.hideAttribution) {
     |                  ^
  58 |         return null;
  59 |     }

My .babelrc contains:
{
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator"
    ]
}  

My package.json also includes the dev dependencies:
"dependencies" : {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.10.3",
}
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
   "@babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.3",
}

I know my babel configuration isn't being ignored, as these errors are ignored throughout the rest of the project, even though the same 'rules' are violated.
my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "lib": ["DOM", "es2020"],
     "jsx": "react", 
     "outDir": "./src/res/scripts", 
     "rootDir": "./src/main",
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                
    "types": ["node"], 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }, 
  "exclude": [
    "./src/debug"
  ]
}

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out why this would be happening, and hoped to find a solution.
